# subtract minutes from calculated time javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime-format, subtraction

I need to subtract minutes from the calculated time

```
var calculatedTime=11.30;// hours
var subtractTime=40;//minutes
var diff=calculatedTime - subtractTime;// How to do this ??
```

How to do this in javascript

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function converToMinutes(s) {
    var c = s.split('.');
    return parseInt(c[0]) * 60 + parseInt(c[1]);
}

function parseTime(s) {
    return Math.floor(parseInt(s) / 60) + "." + parseInt(s) % 60
}
//var minutes = parseTime(EndTIme) - parseTime(StartTime);

var timeToSubtract = 40;
var startTime = converToMinutes('11.30');
var converted = parseTime(startTime - timeToSubtract);
alert(converted);
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/N6vpS/)

Comment: Then do `var timeToSubtract = converToMinutes('1.20');`