# how to convert the minutes into hours and minutes with subtracted time(subtracted time values)

Tags: javascript, datetime, subtraction

I want to subtract the two different 24 hours time format.

I had tried with following :

```
var startingTimeValue = 04:40;
var endTimeValue = 00:55;
var hour = startingTimeValue.split(":");
var hour1 = endTimeValue.split(":");

var th = 1 * hour[0] - 1 * hour1[0];
var tm = 1 * hour[1] - 1 * hour1[1];

var time = th+":"+tm;
```

This code is working fine if second minutes is not greater than the first.but other case           it will return minus values.

The above code sample values result :

```
time1 : 04:40
time2 : 00:55
```

The result should be : 03:45 (h:mi) format. 
But right now I am getting 04:-5 with minus value.

I had tried with the link as : [subtract minutes from calculated time javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570326/subtract-minutes-from-calculated-time-javascript) but this is not working with 00:00 format. 
So how to calculate the result value and convert into hours and minutes?

Comment: Just wondering why your endTime is *before* your startTime? Seems a bit backward ;)

Answer (score 3):

I would try something like the following.
The way I see it, it is always better to break it down to a common unit and then do simple math.

```
function diffHours (h1, h2) {

    /* Converts "hh:mm" format to a total in minutes */
    function toMinutes (hh) {
        hh = hh.split(':');
        return (parseInt(hh[0], 10) * 60) + parseInt(hh[1], 10);
    }

    /* Converts total in minutes to "hh:mm" format */
    function toText (m) {
        var minutes = m % 60;
        var hours = Math.floor(m / 60);

        minutes = (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes;
        hours = (hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + hours;

        return hours + ':' + minutes;
    }

    h1 = toMinutes(h1);
    h2 = toMinutes(h2);

    var diff = h2 - h1;

    return toText(diff);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var time1 = Date.UTC(0,0,0,4,40,0);
var time2 = Date.UTC(0,0,0,0,55,0);

var subtractedValue = time1 - time2;

var timeResult = new Date(subtractedValue);

console.log(timeResult.getUTCHours() + ":" + timeResult.getUTCMinutes());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h4VM7/)

This solution utilizes javascript built-in date. How it works:

```
var time1 = Date.UTC(0,0,0,4,40,0);
var time2 = Date.UTC(0,0,0,0,55,0);
```

*time1*, *time2* is the number of miliseconds since 01/01/1970 00:00:00 UTC.

```
var subtractedValue = time1 - time2;
```

*subtractedValue* is the difference in miliseconds.

```
var timeResult = new Date(subtractedValue);

console.log(timeResult.getUTCHours() + ":" + timeResult.getUTCMinutes());
```

These lines reconstruct a date object to get hours and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This works better , A fiddle I just found

```
var difference = Math.abs(toSeconds(a) - toSeconds(b));
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDnND/14/)

Answer (score 0):

This method may work for you:

```
function timeDiff(s,e){
    var startTime = new Date("1/1/1900 " + s);
    var endTime = new Date("1/1/1900 " + e);
    var diff = startTime - endTime;
    var result = new Date(diff);
    var h = result.getUTCHours();
    var m = result.getUTCMinutes();    
    return (h<=9 ? '0' + h : h) + ':' + (m <= 9 ? '0' + m : m);
}

var startingTimeValue = "04:40";
var endTimeValue = "00:55";
var formattedDifference = timeDiff(startingTimeValue,endTimeValue);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zRVSg/