# Subtract two HH:MM strings with a recursive function

Tags: javascript, time

I've been trying to get [this](http://jsbin.com/EqicImO/3/edit) to work, I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19812982/1067465) and adapted it towards my needs. At the moment it is arriving at the intended value, however the return isn't passed outside the function on the return. I've tried debugging it, but can't seem to find/understand the problem.

The function is supposed to subtract two strings in the format "hh:mm" and return a string in the same format. One of the strings is provided by a user to which we subtract the amount of time needed to provide a service to that given deadline.

Here's the code with console.log() statements that I used to track the values:

```
function subtractMinutes(time, minsToSubtract) {
    /* Converts "hh:mm" format to a total in minutes */
    function toMinutes (hh) {
        //if in the recursion it will be an int instead of a string
        if (hh < 0) {
          return Math.abs(hh);
        }
        hh = hh.split(':');
        return (parseInt(hh[0], 10) * 60) + parseInt(hh[1], 10);
    }

    /* Converts total in minutes to "hh:mm" format */
    function toText (m) {
        var minutes = m % 60;
        var hours = Math.floor(m / 60);

        minutes = (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes;
        hours = (hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + hours;

        return hours + ':' + minutes;
    }
    console.log('time = '+time); //tracking values
    console.log('minsToSubtract = '+minsToSubtract); //tracking values

    time = toMinutes(time);
    console.log('time toMinutes = '+time); //tracking values
    minsToSubtract = toMinutes(minsToSubtract);
    console.log('minsToSubtract toMinutes = '+minsToSubtract); //tracking values

    var diff = time - minsToSubtract;
    console.log('diff = '+diff); //tracking values

    //if in recursion it will have to account for 24h/day instead of going to negative values
    if (diff < 0) {
      subtractMinutes("24:00", diff);
    } 
    //end of recursion when diff>0 and the result may be returned
    else {
      console.log('diff = '+diff); //tracking values
      var result = toText(diff);
      console.log('result = '+result); //tracking values
      return result; //at the end this value is correct, after this point it becomes "undefined"
    }
}
var result = subtractMinutes("0:35", "01:00");
console.log(result);
console.log('---------------------');
```

Any suggestions are very welcome, although packages/plugins/libraries wouldn't be considered.

**-----EDIT-----**

Given [rlemon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21271656/1067465) I tried two different approaches to try and sort this, but it didn't work:

```
    if (diff < 0) {
      subtractMinutes("24:00", diff);
    } 
    //removed the else part of the statement as suggested 
    console.log('diff = '+diff); //tracking values
    var result = toText(diff);
    console.log('result = '+result); //tracking values
    return result;
}
```

This doesn't return `undefined` anymore, however the `toText()` function gets called after the recursion resolves the correct value, thus trying to convert the value for a second time, which returns something like `"0-1:0-25"`.

So thinking I had understood the problem I tried going around the issue another way and did the following:

```
    var result;
    if (diff < 0) {
      subtractMinutes("24:00", diff);
    } else {
      console.log('diff after if= '+diff); //"diff after if= 1415"
      result = toText(diff);
      console.log('result = '+result); //"result = 23:35" CORRECT VALUE
      return result; //tried with this one on and off, same problem
    }
    console.log('result before return = '+result); //"result before return = undefined"
    return result;
}
```

I would like to suggest placing a breakpoint on the last result of my function to see what value is assigned to it and what actually happens to undefine the value.

Comment: `(parseInt(hh[0], 10) * 60) + parseInt(hh[1], 10)` can be `hh[0]*60 + +h[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of the code seems convoluted to me. There is no need for recursion, if the result of the subraction is < 0, simply add 1,440 minutes (24 hrs ). Things should be kept as simple as possible, if not simpler.

e.g.

```
var subtractMins = (function() {

  // Pad numbers < 10 with a leading zero (returns string)
  function z(n) {
    return (n<10? '0':'') + n;
  }

  // Convert hh:mm to minutes (returns number)
  function t2m(t) {
    var b = t.split(':');
    return b[0] * 60 + +b[1];
  }

  // Convert minutes to hh:mm (returns string)
  function m2t(m) {
    return z((m/60 | 0)) + ':' + z(m%60);
  }

  // Return t (time) minus m (minutes) as string
  // t and m are strings in hh:mm format
  // Uses 24 clock so 00:00 - 00:10 => 23:50
  return function(t, m) {
    var r = t2m(t) - (t2m(m) % 1440);
    return m2t(r<0? r + 1440 : r);
  };
}());

alert(subtractMins('00:00','00:10')); // 23:50
alert(subtractMins('01:00','00:10')); // 00:50
alert(subtractMins('01:00','51:10')); // 21:50
```

#### Edit

Modified so that result is within 24hr range.

Comment: I just love the way you clear the mess up with a maximum of 2 statements per function. It does exactly what I need, although the recursion would account for a subtraction of more then a day `subtractMins('01:00','50:00')`, I'm still not certain if that amount could be used so I was trying to have it accounted for, just in case. By the way, how do you call your function creation method? So I can learn a bit more about it `function name() {...}` vs `var name = (function() {...}());`.

Comment: About the function declaration I found it, it's called "self invoking function expression" a simple explanation can be found here: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Comment: There is no need for recursion, I've modified the function to cope with out of bounds results (use mod 1440 on the result before converting to hh:mm). It is always possible to write a recursive function as sequential operations and the result is always faster (unless a clever compiler converts the recursion to sequential).

Comment: The pattern is called an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE). It means the helper functions are created once and are then held in closures so they remain private to the function. It's also used for what is known as the module pattern.

Answer (score 2):

after the first function call there is no return so it return 'undefined'.
take this simplified example:

```
function foo( bar ) {
  if( bar ) {
    foo(false); // okay.. so you hit this and jump out of the if statement.
    // now you think because the return is going to be triggered in the next
    // pass that it will be the end result, but it isn't.
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
  // no return, so return undefined
}
foo(true)
```

changing `subtractMinutes("24:00", diff);` inside the 'recursion' if statement to `return subtractMinutes("24:00", diff);` should solve the issue because now it isn't terminating on the first call.

see the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/2YgyJ/

as a side note: now you don't need to have an 'else' statement there and you can omit it completely and just run the code after the if:

```
//if in recursion it will have to account for 24h/day instead of going to negative values
if (diff < 0) {
    return subtractMinutes("24:00", diff); // because of the return here, the code below is not hit until the if condition returns false
}
//end of recursion when diff>0 and the result may be returned
console.log('diff = ' + diff); //tracking values
var result = toText(diff);
console.log('result = ' + result); //tracking values
return result;
```

Comment: When I remove the else part of the statement it breaks up the result into something like this: `"0-1:0-25"`

Comment: With the else statement the console "says" diff = 35, result = 00:35, undefined, --------------------- Without the else I get this diff = 35, result = 00:35, diff = -1405, result = 0-24:0-25, 0-24:0-25, --------------------- Meaning it goes through the toText funtion within the recursion, where it shouldn't

Comment: I've edited given your response, but I think you need to look directly at the debugger to see what I mean. The debugger shows me that the `result` variable is correct all the way to the finishing curly brace, then it goes back into the function's last return statement and undefines `result`. http://jsbin.com/EqicImO/7/edit